# Facebook on android: When do you openActiveSession and openForRead

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-login

I have a problem when do use `openActiveSession` and when to use `openFoRead`.

Can I just use `openForRead` when user login to facebook with additional read permission, will it also open up an active session as `openActiveSession` does?